# Logicall and physicall adress space counting in OS

Tags: system, paging

Well, i have **16 bit** logical memory address space. My phyical memory address is **20 bits** and size of one page in page table is **512 bytes**. My questions are:

1. How many pages can i fit to my pages table (first level paging)? [i counted *128 pages* but i am not sure that it is right]?
2. How many bytes remains free for additional flags which can have every page in table(the page is **16 bit** large)?
3. Am I right if i will say that *16 bit* logical address space can address only *16 bit* physical address so *4 bits* will be untouchted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i try to answer, but it's been a long time since I have been to school...

LAP: 16 b (address)
FAP: 20 b (address)
Page size: 512 B = 2<sup>9</sup> B  =>  9 b (Offset)
Page table item: 16 b (size)

1. Page address = LAP address − Offset = 16 b − 9 b = 7 b  =>  2<sup>7</sup> = 128 indexes (pages) in page table.
2. Frame base = FAP address − Offset = 20 b − 9 b = 11 b.
   11 b >= 7 b (frame base must be > or = than page address).
   Not used = Page table item − Frame base = 16 b − 11 b = 5 b.
   So we can use 5 bits for flags. But there are also 4 bits from the Frame base (11 b − 7 b = 4 b).
   (?) *I'm not pretty sure whether to use 5 bits or 9 bits for flags...*
3. Not quite, see 2.